# High Log Flush Wait Time and filling Transaction logs

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, transaction-log, wait-types

I have problem with Log Flush Wait Time - as of now, they are averaging at 30000ms (min 0 max 35000); database itself is performing poorly, transaction logs are also growing beyond reasonable description. Log files have to be shrunk to keep the size at bear, not filling up whole disk drive with log files.  I checked DB waits and they are in general `LCK_M_S`, also `OLEDB`. Database itself lives on SQL 2016 Always-on.

I still believe that there may be some SQL server issues with settings - I can also see that there is a lot of SQL Memory pressure (30000 free stalls, ~900000000 page reads, 30000 page life exp.) - server has 32GB RAM, hosting ~80 databases.

I know the application is the probably main reason for this but still, any suggestions on proceedings?

Comment: How often are you taking log backups?

Comment: 4 times - two full and two transaction log

Comment: This is perhaps a good time to review that strategy, and start taking log backups frequently enough to meet your company's RPO (which I assume is fairly stringent, since you're using AGs). Start reading here: https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2011/12/letters-that-get-dbas-fired/

Comment: You might be better off with TLog bacups every 1 hour or even every 15 minutes. However, if you have transactions that never commit, then you might have to sort out that first.

Comment: To elaborate slightly - in the FULL recovery model, SQL has to keep completed transactions in the log until either a FULL backup is done, or until a transaction log backup is done. It sounds like you're taking 4 backups a day that allow SQL to release old completed transactions and reuse log space. If you take transaction log backups more frequently, the log will be able to clear the old transactions and reuse space sooner, and won't need to grow as large. Currently, shrinking the log files just means that SQL has to grow them back out (which won't help performance).

Comment: OK I will start with more frequent transaction log backups; also I will try to sort out the problems with the application itself. But there is still the serious degradation of performance issue - those numbers that I posted are never even close to the slow - they are disastrous, don't you agree?

Comment: Hey, this can be closed - sorry to disappoint with no extra answer - but the application IS the main culprit; the nature of the coding is the problem itself. Thank you for all the input!!

Comment: Voting to close since the problem ended up being local to the application iteslf.

Answer (score 3):

Usual supect, in this case: The **IO subsystem is slow**. Are you using SSDs?

DMVs are your friends.

Identity & Isolate Issues

Log Flush Wait Time

- This is an indication of Underlying IO bottleneck
- What is the write latency?
- Find out using `sys.dm_io_virtual_file_stats` &
  `sys.dm_io_pending_io_requests`

Size log files appropriately

- Your application seems to be a very high transactional load type.
- If log files are frequenting to a certain size limit, it means it needs such size.
- I would size my log files to be 750 MB if the log file is frequently reaching that size at its peak.

Transactional log backups

- Maybe you just need a more frequent log backup.
- Test & decide.

As far as memory, a 30000 PLE looks good to me on a 32 GB RAM server. Assuming this is SQL's memory, not the server's.

Resources:

- [Paul Randal](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/94938/paul-s-randal)'s [Transaction Log Monitoring](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/11/sql-performance/transaction-log-monitoring)
- Paul Randal's [Page Life Expectancy](https://sqlperformance.com/2014/10/sql-performance/knee-jerk-page-life-expectancy)